# MongoDB “E11000 duplicate key error index” when creating saving a mongoengine ReferenceField (DBRef)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am attempting to load testing fixtures from a json file in my test runs (to match a similar style of fixture loading used in Django). This is the code I've got so far;

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
from mongoengine import base as mongobase
from mongoengine import connect
from pymongo import json_util

db = connect("DATABASENAME")

# Clear out the current collections.
for collection in db.collection_names():
    if collection == 'system.indexes':
        continue
    db.drop_collection(collection)


# Open json fixtures

f = open('path/to/test_fixtures.json', 'r')
datas = json.loads(f.read(), object_hook=json_util.object_hook)

# For each serialised model instance, loop through and save to the database.

for data in datas:

    print data

    if data['_cls'] not in mongobase._document_registry:
        print "Skipping %s" % data['_cls2']
        continue

    model = mongobase._document_registry[data['_cls']]
    model_instance = model._from_son(data)
    model_instance.save(force_insert=True)
```

This mostly seems to work, however, when one of the models has a ReferenceField, it fails. Complaining about a duplicate key. You'll notice there is a print statement in there to show the dict contents, in an example run I'll get the following output which all looks fine before the error

```
{u'_types': [u'Account'], u'status': u'ok', u'name': u'Alice', u'local_id': u'3', u'_cls': u'Account', u'members': [], u'_id': ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000001'), u'email': u'alice@example.com', u'permissions': []}
{u'_types': [u'Account'], u'status': u'ok', u'name': u'Bob', u'local_id': u'2', u'_cls': u'Account', u'members': [], u'_id': ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000000'), u'email': u'bob@example.com', u'permissions': []}
{u'_types': [u'Account'], u'status': u'ok', u'name': u'company', u'_cls': u'Account', u'members': [], u'_id': ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000002'), u'email': u'org@example.com', u'permissions': []}
{u'_types': [u'Membership'], u'parent_account': DBRef(u'account', ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000002')), u'member': DBRef(u'account', ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000001')), u'role': u'member', u'_cls': u'Membership', u'_id': ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000003')}
```

Finally, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/engineclub/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 292, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/engineclub/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 259, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/vagrant/engineclub/engineclub/apps/notifications/tests.py", line 67, in _fixture_setup
    model_instance.save(force_insert=True)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/engineclub/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 177, in save
    _refs=_refs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/engineclub/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 183, in save
    raise OperationError(message % unicode(err))
OperationError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: test_aliss.account.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('4f17f0855585d32457000001') })
```

It seems to be complaining about a duplicate key on account.$*id* when inserting a *membership* instance which has a reference to the account collection only.

Let me know if there is any other information I can include, I would have added the JSON file however, its very much like the printed dicts (and only has 3 accounts followed by one membership). One thing I did notice, when I remove the force_insert from the save, it doesn't seem to save anything at all (and thus appears to pass fine).

Comment: I take it you are providing the object id's manually and therefore are creating the DBRef objects with ids hardcoded.

Also are the Accounts saved correctly?  I'm wondering if some dereferencing issue is happening and when you save the membership its trying to resave the Account object.

Comment: Yup, the object ID's are being manually provided. I suspect the problem could be to do with this, mongoengine doesn't really seem to help with serialisation. The accounts are being saved, I  added a quick line in the loop that done this: ``print data, Account.objects.count(), Membership.objects.count()`` and the counts was increasing for the accounts (membership stuck at 0 as the first failed)

Comment: It might be easier to deal with pymongo direct and save the data in the correct collections.  Provide me a test case and I'll look into it - add a ticket on github

Comment: how are you creating the fixture files?

Comment: @JosephMisiti with the method described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongoengine-users/HIBCxTg1zQ0

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Mixer](https://github.com/klen/mixer):

```
from mixer.backend.mongoengine import mixer

mixer.blend(MyDocument)
```